# How to vertically align text in div which in an inline-block div?

Tags: html, css

Pls see the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/0kwnL8k8/

```
<div>        
    <div class="container divinline">
    <div class="row1 ">ROW ONE</div>
    <div class="row2">ROW TWO</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divinline{
    display:inline-block;
}

.container{
    line-height:60px;
    height:60px;
    background:#ffee12;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
}

.row1{
    background:#450011;
    font-size:12px;
    height:50%;
    line-height:50%;
}

.row2{
    background:#333333;
    font-size:12px;
    height:50%;
    line-height:50%;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

I don't know why the text in row1 and row2 overlapped the border of the two divs.  I want to vertical-align them to the bottom.  Anybody know the reason?

Many thanx.

Comment: It is the `line-height` settings.

Comment: I would not recommend that you do `50%` height because you really do not need it to be responsive when it is that small and only have a few items. I would however suggest to use `<ul>` instead of what you have and give the `[class of ul] li` a `line-height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just halve your `height` / `line-height` in `.container` and remove the `height:50%;` and `line-height:50%;` from `.row1` and `.row2`.

So your container class would be:

```
.container{
    line-height:30px; //half previous value
    height:30px; //half previous value
    background:#ffee12;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

And remove 50% height from `row1` and `row2`

```
.row1{
    background:#450011;
    font-size:12px;
}

.row2{
    background:#333333;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0kwnL8k8/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Dan's answer - http://jsfiddle.net/0kwnL8k8/4/
but I added another 'row' class for use in all rows. This does assume that the height is constant 30px.

```
.row {
  line-height:30px;
  height:50%;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question : [How to vertically align text in the middle of a div that has a percentage height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853679/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-the-middle-of-a-div-that-has-a-percentage-height/25853875)

In your case it could be : http://jsfiddle.net/0kwnL8k8/5/

```
.row1:before, .row2:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

*See answer linked here on SO, to manage multilines if that happens*