# How to vertically align text in the middle of a div that has a percentage height?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Here is what I have right now. In other divs using `vertical-align:middle`and setting the `line-height` to the same value as the `height` property it should work!The only thing is that in those divs I used pixel dimension and not percentages. Can anybody tell me why this wont work with percentages? also setting the `text-size`to 50% should also make text half the size of the div but it is really really small still? What is going on here?

```
#chooseStateAlabama {
    width: 20%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../_images/_unitedStates/_states/chooseStateAlabama.png);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50%;
    line-height: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code including HTML or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: `font-size` is not related to the parent element's height. It's related to the base font size. Ditto for `line-height`.

Comment: This is what happens! http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` , `height:100%` and `vertical-align:middle` to a single element or pseudo element aside the text (before or after): [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/1/)

```
#chooseStateAlabama:before {/* this can be an extra tag within HTML structure if pseudo used for other purpose */
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

If you happen to have more content or more than 1 line, then use an element to wrap it as well and apply to it display and vertical-align. [DEMO2 to see behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/4/)

Comment: Thank you! That did it! :) Can you answer one more question? How to you make text-size responsive to the size of the div it is in?

Comment: @figureoa.kyle710 you cannot really do this without javascript. you could take a look at vw units , wich will take the screen width as a reference Your demo could use 5vw or whatever else since you use % 100% then 20% , wich is 100vw and 20vw here

Comment: Okay, maybe i'll have to take a look into a little java script for it! Thanks again!!

Comment: @figureoa.kyle710 check this if your demo is close to your reality : http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/6/ (read update of my previous comment too :) )

Comment: Perfect! Had to adjust some measurements for my real situation but I got it and it works perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: add width: 100% also

Comment: @Dvir *not at all*, no width is required because it should be  widthless at first , unless you want to push content out of the box , but why ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the markup you can use quite a few ways to get the result you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/vvpn6cge/

Because you have text ( that could be one or many lines long I guess) then you could get the result using CSS table cells (see the fiddle).

```
.outer-container {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.txt-vertical-align {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a further alternative, you might use flexbox

```css
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
align-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
```

(stolen from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div))

Comment: for the flex, there is even a easier way to do : http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/4/ container in display:flex : height and width , and a child set with: margin:auto;

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/L85h8vvj/7/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class='container4'>
    <div>Example :)</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin:0px;
}
div.container4 {
height: 100%;
width:100%;
position: absolute;
}

div.container4 div {
margin: 0;
background: yellow;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: 50-%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
```